# Is resolve() can can be called implicitly in $q from anjularjs?

Tags: angularjs, promise

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
From the document of the $q API, then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback.
However, the website gives an example which does not call resolve explicitly

```
 promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
    return result + 1;
  });

  // promiseB will be resolved immediately after promiseA is resolved and its value
  // will be the result of promiseA incremented by 1
```

So the calling then function will create a newly derived promise, but how does $q know its state because the code is not calling resolve() or reject()? But since the website says it is resolved, so I assume

```
return result + 1;
```

is calling resolve() implicitly, is it correct? Hence, if I don't call reject() explicitly and keep calling then() and return some value, promises will always be in resolve states but I don't need to call resolve explicitly?

Comment: `$q` is notified about a new state when `promiseA` is resolved, e.g. when it is a deferred on which `.resolve()` is called

Comment: The 'technical' term is that `.then` is both a `map` and a `flatMap` I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not resolved immediately. As the comment says:

> promiseB will be resolved immediately after promiseA is resolved

So, when the `promiseA` promise is resolved (and only then), the `promiseB` promise will also be resolved, with the resolved result of `promiseA` incremented by 1.

You have to explicitely resolve `promiseA` to also resolve `promiseB`.

If the promiseA is already resolved when you call then() on it to create the promiseB, then the promiseB will be resolved immediately.

Comment: Can I reject promiseB? So the state of promiseA determines the state of promiseB? I reject promiseB calling reject(), but promiseB can be resolved without calling resolve()?

Comment: You don't call resolve() on a promise. You call resolve() on a deferred. When resolve() is called on the deferred, its promise, and all the derived promises of its promise, are resolved.

Comment: @JBNizet you should edit that last comment into your answer - it's the crux of the issue OP is having. It's also worth mentioning how `.then` works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *yes*, promise B **is** implicitly resolved.

When you register a callback promise (B) with a `.then()`, angular puts it into an array of `$$pending` callbacks. After the original promise (A) is resolved, angular goes through calling `.resolve()` on the `$$pending` callbacks, passing the function inside as an argument.

In the example, angular would internally run something like the following:

```
promiseB.resolve((function(result){
  return result + 1;
})(resultFromA))
```

Have a look at [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L3) for a more in-depth view of what's going on.